# Create images using a template and table of data

Tags: images, csv, templates

How to create many images from a template and table of data?

E.g., many business cards from a CSV file containing names, positions, and contacts?

I realize there're ways of doing it by writing a script, say with `svgwriter` in Python or Python + LaTeX, but maybe special software exists already?

PS: A similar problem is mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/418680/generating-a-pdf-using-data-rows-from-excel-and-an-image-as-the-template-with-pl), though I have somewhat weaker demands: any image would be fine, not only PDF. I just wonder if this simple task have more user-friendly implementations.

Comment: Actually a PDF is, to me, a *weaker* demand (since you only focus on a single filetype rather than the *billions* there are out there). Have you tried the solution? If so, why didn't it work for you?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_merge

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating a pdf using data rows from excel and an image as the template with placeholders](http://superuser.com/questions/418680/generating-a-pdf-using-data-rows-from-excel-and-an-image-as-the-template-with-pl)

Comment: @DoktoroReichard I believe that solution a little bit overkill for simple copy-paste templates. Let's take a meme generator: it's a much more convenient thing that writing scripts, as described in the other topic. (But it's inflexible in templates.) I wanted to make sure (or happily proven to be mistaken) that there's no simple web service that provides such operations.

Comment: @techie007 Thanks for Mail merge — I'll investigate. As for the duplicate: I had this link in my post, but that link mention PDF, which is not a necessary condition for me. So, maybe there're more solutions exist.

Comment: @Anton but someone somewhere *had* to write a PHP (or other language) script in order for the meme generator to work. Your question seems contrived: you ask for a service that parses a CSV file (a very specific demand) and then creates a picture (that has no printing settings whatsoever, unlike a PDF, where the page settings are clearly done). You are asking for too much. If you give up on one of the demands I think you will find a tool that helps you. Maybe if you rewrote the question **highlighting** these details you might get more help.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard I agree. Maybe the request is imprecise. I needed software that does the job without programming. Otherwise, I would post this request on StackOverflow. In fact, *techie007* suggested Mail merge. OpenOffice [has](http://blog.worldlabel.com/mail-merge-in-openofficeorg-everything-you-need-to-know) this feature, and that's the closest fit.

Comment: If you in the end solve your problem, feel free to post an answer, as to help others with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

As @techie007 suggested, [Wikipedia article on Mail merge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_merge) contained links to some software solutions that allow creating mass prints from a given template and data sources. OpenOffice [can](http://blog.worldlabel.com/mail-merge-in-openofficeorg-everything-you-need-to-know) do this. Also specialized software (such as the one used for printing business cards) also can do the job.

Answer (score 0):

This question is ten years old now, but there are still people seeking to use mail merge procedures to combine a template with a data source.

A few years ago I wrote a powershell function that uses a csv file as a data source, and plugs that data into a template, producing repetitive expansions.  It's a lot like mail merge.

The template can be almost any kind of code:  SQL,  HTML,  or even a PS1 function call with variables in the arguments.  The variables in the template look like powershell variables, and have the same names as the fields in the csv files.

If you want to see the whole package, including a demo, see github.com/dcressey/expand-csv

If you just want to look at the source,  here it is:

```
<#
.NOTES
    Script: Expand-Csv    Rev:  3.2
    Author: DGC           Date: 2-21-19
.SYNOPSIS
    Generates multiple expansions of a template,
    driven by data in a CSV file.
.DESCRIPTION
    This function is a table driven template tool. 

    It generates output from a template and
    a driver table.  The template file contains plain
    text and embedded variables.  The driver table 
    (in a csv file) has one column for each variable, 
    and one row for each expansion to be generated.
#>
function Expand-csv {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
       [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $driver,
       [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $template
    )
    Process {
       Import-Csv $driver | % {
           $_.psobject.properties | % {Set-variable -name $_.name -value $_.value}
           Get-Content $template | % {$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($_)} 
       }
    }
}
```